# Add Rows and Columns to Google DataTable Net Wrapper

Tags: c#, charts, google-visualization, google-datatable

I am creating a Google DataTable Net Wrapper DataTable from the scratch. But I dont know how to add rows to the datatable. I have progressed to the code as below

```
Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper.DataTable GDt = new Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper.DataTable();
for (int i = 0; i < dtReports.Columns.Count; i++)
{
    Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper.Column gc = new Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper.Column();
    gc.Id = dtReports.Columns[i].Caption.Substring(0, dtReports.Columns[i].Caption.IndexOf("~"));
    gc.Label = dtReports.Columns[i].Caption.Substring(dtReports.Columns[i].Caption.IndexOf("~"), dtReports.Columns[i].Caption.Length);
    GDt.AddColumn(gc);

    for (int j = 0; j < dtReports.Rows.Count; j++)
    {
        Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper.Row gr = GDt.NewRow();

        // Code to add datatable current column and row value to Google Row
    }
}
```

Not able to find code to add the values to the row and particular column. Help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it which fits with your existing code:

```
for (int j = 0; j < dtReports.Rows.Count; j++)
{
    // Code to add datatable current column and row value to Google Row
    Google.DataTable.Net.Wrapper.Row gr = i == 0 ? GDt.NewRow() : GDt.Rows.ElementAt(j);
    gr.AddCell(new Cell(dtReports.Rows[j][i]));
    if (i == 0) GDt.AddRow(gr);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this fitted perfectly for my code.